# how does $2*4*6....(2n)$ turn into $2^n* n! $ in this power series?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

How do they change the denominator from the equation into $2^{n}n!$ in this case? Isn't it just $2n$ as $n$ approaches infinity?
[image]

Comment: Factor out a 2 from each factor.

Comment: You might also want to read [double factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

$$\begin{align*}
2\cdot 4\cdot 6\cdot\ldots\cdot(2n)&=(2\cdot\color{crimson}1)\cdot(2\cdot\color{crimson}2)\cdot(2\cdot\color{crimson}3)\cdot\ldots\cdot(2\cdot \color{crimson}n)\\
&=(\underbrace{2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot\ldots\cdot2}_{n\text{ factors}})\cdot(\color{crimson}{1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot\ldots\cdot n})\\
&=2^n\cdot\color{crimson}{n!}
\end{align*}$$